# Finding an array object ID by property

Tags: javascript, arrays

This may be a duplicate, but I'm not sure.

I have the following array:

```
[
  {
    id: "object1"
  },
  {
    id: "object2"
  },
  {
    id: "object3"
  }
]
```

The trick is, the array is dynamic, and, therefore, the global IDs of this array objects vary. For example, array[1] in one case may be an object with id "object1", and, in other case, that with an id of "object3".

How to query this array based on the id string and have the array index as the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` into an object indexed by `id`, with the values being the index of that `id`'s object in the original array, and then you can use simple object lookup:

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: "object1"
  },
  {
    id: "object2"
  },
  {
    id: "object3"
  }
];
const indexedById = input.reduce((a, { id }, i) => {
  a[id] = i;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(indexedById.object2); // index of 1 in input
```

`.findIndex` is another possibility, but it has worse time complexity than object lookup.

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting the number I need, but right after that there's console error "Uncaught TypeError: object2 is not a function". I'm working in React.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call `object2` as a function, but it's not a function, nor is it even a standalone variable - it's only a *property* of the accumulator

Comment: then how to call it properly to find the id of the object it is in?

Comment: Don't call it like a function, just access that property name, like in the snippet: `indexedById.object2`

Comment: in order to find the index, we create an object. This is not very efficient. Sorry, maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: I am getting "undefined" :/

Comment: @D.Seah If it's just done once, sure, but if it's something that needs to be *queried*, creating a lookup table like this in advance is not a bad idea at all.

Comment: @Ruham Press "Run code snippet" - you can see for yourself, the code *does* work

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to accept another answer, since it did what is needed without giving any errors.

Comment: My bad! Your code works as well! Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Since findIndex returns immediately once it's found a match, it's more efficient if you're only looking for an object by id value once, but @CertainPerformance is right -- if you plan on doing this frequently, creating an object to look up ids makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Array has a `findIndex`, so you could do `const findById = (x) => xs.findIndex(({ id }) => id === x)` where `x` is your id string and `xs` is your array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems not working inside of a React function, and what is xs?

Comment: I added a note in my answer; `xs` would be the array you're searching through. You could also have the function _take_ your array, like `const findById = (x, xs) => xs.findIndex...`etc.